# Microsoft.StreamProcessing causes exception on program loading

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mef

I have a somewhat complex trading application that handles lots of Event messages. It is a `Windows` `MEF` application that loads `assemblies` automatically at `runtime`.

I decided to try  `Microsoft.StreamProcessing` to convert events to `IStreamable`. I moved in slow steps. First, I just added the assembly through `nuget` to my `project`. Then added

`using Microsoft.StreamProcessing;`

to the code, but did not declare any types. Runs fine.

Next, I added a **single** line to the code:

`IStreamable<Empty, IQuote> markeDatatStream`;

That's all I did. I am not using it in any way, just added that one line. This time, while the program is loading, I get the following exception. When I look inside the recommended `LoaderExceptions` field, I get:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

If I **remove** the single line from the code

`IStreamable<Empty, IQuote> markeDatatStream`;

It works fine.

The full exception:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131602
  Message=Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InternalGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TryGetExports(ExportProvider provider, ComposablePart part, ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportSubset(PartManager partManager, IEnumerable`1 imports, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.TryInvoke(Action action)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch batch)
   at Trader.MainForm.InitializeTradingEngine() in C:\Users\idf\Projects\Trader-Orig-Working\Trader\Trader\MainForm.cs:line 200
   at Trader.MainForm..ctor(String logFilePath) in C:\Users\idf\Projects\Trader-Orig-Working\Trader\Trader\MainForm.cs:line 113
   at Trader.Program.Main() in C:\Users\idf\Projects\Trader-Orig-Working\Trader\Trader\Program.cs:line 231
```

Comment: Guess you need a `<bindingRedirect>`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: I don't follow. How does that help the problem that I have?

Comment: explained in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is probably [strong naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies).

In summary:

If you include library A, which is strong named, and uses library B with assembly-version 1.0.0.0
and you are using Library B, but with assembly-version 1.1.0.0, then you will get loads errors - with the confusing error "The system cannot find the file specified"

You need then a binding:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="B"     publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"     culture="en-us" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

So someone builds to System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, in your application, but you're probably (maybe via another library) providing another version of  System.Runtime.Loader.

another option is add the System.Runtime.Loader versions to the GAC

Comment: I see. Inside the app.config file I see a bunch of these very statements. So the question then becomes, is the correct way to fix this is instead of messing with the app.config file, wouldn't just adding the assembly from nuget effectively do the same thing, but in a more systemic way?

Comment: There are 3 options, use the GAC, use everywhere the exact same version or use the bindingRedirect. The latter is pretty common these days.

Comment: This is dll-hell all over again if you ask me.